# JQuery Show Animation From a Different Direction

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you change the direction of jQuery's hide('slow')/show('slow') animation? By default it uses a combination of fading and sliding to/from the top-left. How would I change that to slide to/from the bottom-center or some other arbitrary direction?

For an example of a modified hide('slow') that slides to bottom-center, I tried doing `$(el).animate({opacity:0, height:0, marginBottom:0})`, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it animates to that point is because your element is relatively positioned by its top left point. In order to animate to the bottom center you will need to have an absolutely positioned element, and you will need to animate its height, width, bottom and left properties to get the effect that you want.

Comment: Thanks, that was it exactly. Simply setting bottom:0; in my CSS accomplished the effect without having to modify my jQuery usage.